# Convert a list of list into a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that looks like this :

```
[['a', 'b', 100], ['b', 'c', 200], ['c', 'd', 300]]
```

And what I want to do is to convert this into Dataframe where index and columns are `['a','b','c','d']` and what I want should look like this:

[Desired DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w3al.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you tried to make your dataframe so far and what's the output?

Comment: @BrunoPicasso If you find my solution helpful, I'd appreciate it if you mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Albo Of course! sorry my bad. I'm new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = [['a', 'b', 100], ['b', 'c', 200], ['c', 'd', 300]]

col_idx = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
x = [ord(x) - 97 for x, _, _ in values]
y = [ord(y) - 97 for _, y, _ in values]
v = [v for _, _, v in values]
A = np.zeros((len(col_idx), len(col_idx)), dtype=np.int)
A[x, y] = v

df = pd.DataFrame(A.T + A, columns=col_idx, index=col_idx)
```

you will get `df` as:

```markdown
|    |   a |   b |   c |   d |
|:---|----:|----:|----:|----:|
| a  |   0 | 100 |   0 |   0 |
| b  | 100 |   0 | 200 |   0 |
| c  |   0 | 200 |   0 | 300 |
| d  |   0 |   0 | 300 |   0 |
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Here is my solution:
''' 
w = pd.DataFrame({'nombre': nombre})
w.set_index('nombre', inplace = True)
df1 = pd.concat([w, pd.DataFrame(columns = nombre)])
df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, 0)
for i in lista:
    df1[i[0]][i[1]] = i[2]
    df1[i[1]][i[0]] = i[2]
    
df1'''
I have previously defined the names and values via input